# Data transmission via laser illuminating the ceiling

Tags: laser, signal-processing

I've heard a data transmission technique proposed more than once wherein a base station would fire a laser at the ceiling of an indoor space. The pulsing of this laser would be observed by one or more omnidirectional receivers (mounted on wireless devices such as phones) which would decode the signal, resulting in short-range high-bandwidth data transmission system, at least in one direction. Basically an optical fiber without the fiber. The intention would be to achieve a multi-gigabit connection that could stream video.

Does this work and if not, why? I can't find any discussion of it online and the few similar systems I've found invariably involve rotating the emitter and receiver to face each other, suggesting there is some problem with this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called optical wireless communication. It has been demonstrated many times in the lab, going back to at least the 1990's. There have been attempts at commercialization, for example under the name [Li-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li-Fi) but none have been especially successful.

Comment: Indeed, the use case really isn’t compelling these days.

Comment: The intended use case is transmission of uncompressed video to a VR headset, which requires a multi-gigabit link in one direction only.

Comment: @user22919 The use case question belongs into the business stackexchange, where a business major can explain to us in detail why that's a really bad business model idea. The implementation details are more of a question for electrical engineering, I am afraid. One could discuss in that context why e.g. your initial assumptions of wide beams is technologically not necessary. That's not a physics question, though, because it resides almost on the level of bill of materials for a product design.

Comment: I mention it only because I realized I never specified the target amount of bandwidth in the original question, making the question trivial. A person flicking a light switch on and off could obviously transmit data to devices with webcams at a few bits a second, the question is if/what physical issues arise when trying to increase the transmission rate.